# How to save checkbox value check/uncheck to NSUserDefault

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I have checkbox Remember Password (for login form). and I want when I check remember it save and form run it show checkbox check. if i uncheck it run and show checkbox uncheck. please share me. thank in advance

Answer (score 7):

Bind the checkbox value binding to some key on the shared user defaults controller:

[image]

(You didn't specifically say whether this is iOS or Mac, but because there's no standard checkbox control in iOS, I assumed the latter.)

Comment: then this is a perfect use case for Cocoa bindings.

Comment: How do you read that on the code?

Comment: @Idan: for example like this (in Swift): `NSUserDefaultsController.sharedUserDefaultsController().valueForKeyPath("values.shouldRunCI")`

Answer (score 1):

Use `-setBool:forKey:` method for `NSUserDefaults`.

```
if(checked)
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:true forKey:@"RememberMe"];
else
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:false forKey:@"RememberMe"];
```

and then you'll be able to get an **actual** BOOL value returned like this:

```
BOOL checked = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"RememberMe"];
```

**EDIT** : Don't forgot to add `synchronize` as this call `NSUserDefaults` to save data immediately

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

Answer (score 1):

On .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, unsafe_unretained) IBOutlet NSButton *isCheckedButton;
```

On .m file

```
@synthesize isCheckedButton;

- (IBAction)changeButtonState:(id)sender{
if ([isCheckedButton state]) { // Check if button is checked
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
    NSLog(@"Change state to On");
}else{
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:FALSE forKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
     NSLog(@"Change state to Off");
}
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize]; // ** DON'T FORGET THIS LINE! ** //
}
```

Above code could be simpler but this is how I think it's better understood.
You can always read the value with:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"YOUR KEY HERE"];
```

Answer (score 0):

you try this:

```
- (void)checkboxButton:(id)sender
 {

 if ( checkboxSelected == 1){

[ checkbox setSelected:NO];
[checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

checkboxSelected = 0;
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger: checkboxSelected forKey:@"checkboxstate"];

 } else {
[checkbox setSelected:YES];
[checkbox setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkbox-checked.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
 checkboxSelected = 1;
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[prefs setInteger: checkboxSelected forKey:@"checkboxstate"];

}



}
```

Comment: yeah, I develop on Mac application but your code guide me the idea. thank you.